# What executes first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, save

In my rails app I have a User model.

In that model I have some custom validation and a before save block as below

```
Class User < AvtiveRecord::Base
  before_save :save_user
  validate :validate_user

  def save_user
    self.guest = true if(!self.admin? && !self.guest)
  end

  def validate_user
    errors.add(:age, "can't be less than 20") if self.age < 20
  end
end
```

Now, I just wanted to know that whether the validate block executes first or the validate. Because there are other validations based on the user role. So if the validate block executes first and there are no validation errors and then the before save executes and modifies the values. Are those values again validated?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validations are called before before_save callbacks. If you want it to execute before the validations then you can use before_validation_on_create or before_validation_on_update, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation_on_create :save_user
  validate :validate_user

  def save_user
    self.guest = true if(!self.admin? && !self.guest)
  end

  def validate_user
    errors.add(:age, "can't be less than 20") if self.age < 20
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Those values will not be validated again. Validation happens once as does save, otherwise you could end up in a looping condition anytime you changed a value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the guide you want: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Based on section 10, it looks as if validation happens first.

I don't think the values will be validated again—there's nothing that would cause that to happen.